# PathTooLongException with Hebrew file names

Tags: c#, path, hebrew

I am trying to upload a file with a Hebrew name.

If I try to do this with an English name it works normally.

This is the path I am trying to write and the file

```
\\10.10.10.120\hrmarket\dev\ניסוי.pdf
```

I double checked the path length and it is 65 characters long, so runtime says.

This is how I try to write it

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

Whenever this is executed I get a PathTooLong Exception.

I am compiling on 4.6.2 and I tried using other libraries that solve the whole PathTooLong issue but they also threw the same error.

Comment: It is possible that the server you are writing to have issues with Hebrew. Do you get the same error when you write to a local file as well?